# Fourier series expansion of $\frac{\pi^4}{96}$ and $\frac{\pi^4}{90}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series

I have to prove that:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\pi^4}{96}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} \qquad \mbox{and} \qquad \frac{\pi^4}{90}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}
\end{equation}

**My idea:**

I've expanded $f(x)=|x|$ in a real Fourier series $\forall x\in Q:=[-\pi,\pi)$:
\begin{equation}
 f(x)=|x|=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2\pi}\cos(nx)
\end{equation}
Now, using Parseval's Identity, I get:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{2\pi^2}{3}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{16}{n^4\pi^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{2}
\end{equation}
hence:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\pi^4}{96}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}
\end{equation}
Now, how can I prove the second claim?

Comment: If you do the same procedure with $x^2$ on $\left[ -\pi,\pi\right]$ you should be able to prove the second claim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *how can I prove the second claim?*

If you already know that
$$
\frac{\pi^4}{90}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}
$$ then observe that (by separating even and odd integers)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^4}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^4}.
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can't see how I can use this expansion of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}$. I'm sorry.

Comment: By writing $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^4}=\frac1{16}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}$$ then...

Answer (score 0):

From what you've already proved:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n^4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac 1{(2n+1)^4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{(2n)^4},$$
whence 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n^4}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{(2n)^4}=\frac{15}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{96}.$$