# Prove the series formula for $\frac{\pi^4}{96}$ using Parseval's Identity

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, power-series, fourier-series, parsevals-identity

I have seen this post [Fourier series expansion of $\frac{\pi^4}{96}$ and $\frac{\pi^4}{90}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604850/fourier-series-expansion-of-frac-pi496-and-frac-pi490) but it seems to skip some steps that I don't understand. I also looked at some others, but I haven't found one that exactly answers what I need.

Using $f(e^{i\theta}) = |\theta|$. I found the Fourier series to be

$$|\theta| = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ik\theta}}{k^2}$$

$c_k = \begin{cases}
0 & \ \mathrm{if} \ k \ \mathrm{is \ even} \\
\frac{-2}{\pi k^2} & \ \mathrm{if} \ k \ \mathrm{ is \ odd} \\ \end{cases}$

So, one could say

$$|\theta| = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ik\theta}}{(2k+1)^2}$$

Now, for Parseval's identity, we need $|c_k|^2 = \frac{4}{\pi^2 (2k+1)^4}$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(e^{i\theta})|^2 d\theta = \frac{\pi^2}{3}$.

So,this means $$\frac{\pi^2}{3} = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{4}{\pi^2(2k+1)^4}.$$

So,

$$\frac{\pi^4}{12} = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^4}.$$

From here is where I am having problems. I'm unsure of how to convert this Fourier series to its equivalent starting at $1$. I thought it was just
$$\frac{\pi^4}{12} = 2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^4},$$ but this is of course not true as the result would be
$$\frac{\pi^4}{24} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^4},$$ which is not the correct answer. (Edit: This part is correct, the answer is just not coming out correctly somehow.) I'm really not sure what the issue is. I did the same process using $f(e^{i\theta}) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \ -\pi < \theta < 0 \\
1 & \ 0 < \theta < \pi \end{cases}$ to prove the series for $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$, but it does not seem to be working here. Does anyone see what's happening?

Comment: Notice that the terms for $k=0$ and $k=-1$ are the same, the terms for $k=1$ and $k=-2$ are the same, and so on...

Comment: First thing I noticed is that there's something odd going on with $k=0$. (Technically, your infiinte sum should be $k=-\infty, -1$ and $k=1,\infty$ as $-2/\pi k^2$ is not defined at $k=0$. )

Comment: Second thing I noticed is that your Parseval's identity doesn't seem right. You want to evaluate $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f|^2 d\theta$ as this is equal to $\sum c_k^2$.

Comment: @daruma I thought that is why we found the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ term. That is the $c_0$ term found by a separate formula. The second thing you mentioned was a typo. I did indeed do it that way. The result is $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$

Comment: @Nicolas I'm not sure I see the point of that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @bomb456 This is to tell you that the sum ranging form $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is two times the some ranging from $0$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: @Nicolas so I was right. I am so confused then. Why is it not coming out correctly? It's off by a factor of $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @bomb456 My first point is a bit of a pedantry. What I am trying to say is that your indices in your infinite sums is technically not correct if you write $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and likewise for your definition of $c_n$.

Comment: I think what you are missing is that you have the $\pi^2/4$ contribution from your $c_0$ term so you should get $\pi^2/12$ is equal to $2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k^2$

Comment: Alright, so I'd just write underneath the $k = -\infty$ that $k \neq 0$. That'll fix that. Now wait, can you share some steps on how you got to that conclusion? Where did the 2 come from? And what about the $\frac{\pi}{12}$? I think some more details would help

Comment: The first Fourier series is obviously not correct as we can see by taking $\theta=0$. The way it is written is indeed strange as it has an issue for $k=0$.

Comment: @Nicolas if you convert that series to a real series, you get the answer in my book. Unless if the complex Fourier series is not equivalent to the real one. If so I'd really like to know why. That would be a major flaw in my understanding

Comment: @bomb456 The series involving cosine and sine functions ranges from $0$ to $+\infty$, maybe there is an error there. Anyway, if I compute the $c_n(f)$ coefficients, I get $-\frac{1}{k^2\pi}$ which explains the factor $4$ in Parseval's identity. Are you sure you divided by $2\pi$ and not only by $\pi$ in the computation? Maybe the error comes from my computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize what happened in the comments, the problem is that you forgot to factor in the $c_0^2$ term when doing your series.

$\pi^2/3=\pi^2/4+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k^2$

here we noted that $c_{-k}=c_k$ so we grouped the sum together to get a series from $1$ to $\infty$.

Now, $$\frac{\pi^2}{3}-\frac{\pi^2}{4}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{\pi^2(2n+1)^4}$$
(here $k=2n+1$ as we omit all the even terms).

So we get $$\frac{\pi^4}{96}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}$$

Comment: I think you forgot your $\pi^2/4$ which would explain why you were out by a factor of $4$.

Comment: Have you checked the formula $c_k(f)=-\frac{2}{k^2\pi}$? I did not find it but could have flawed my computation. EDIT: It's fine actually, I've missed the factor 2!

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. This totally makes sense. When I did $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$, I had $c_0 = 0$, so I didn't even know I had forgotten it! This definitely cleared it up. Thank you!

Comment: Dropped a $\pi^2$?